# Excel Named cell as a column inside of a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value in A1 that is a named cell.  I want to use that value to perform an equation on a column.  Something like:  sum(ColumnTest:ColumnTest)

So `If A1 = "C"` and its a Named cell `"ColumnTest"`

so If I typed the following into B1 I would get "6".  `=Sum(ColumnTest:ColumnTest)`

```
C1 = 1

C2 = 2

C3 = 3
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ColumnTest&":"&ColumnTest))
```

or simply:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1&":"&A1))
```

if the cell wasn't named.